# Text box filter that shows product results

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a selection table (maybe not the right name) for a wordpress shop.

The products have to many subcategories and sub subcategories to make easy to filter from there. And to many criteria for the filter of the shop.

Lets say I have pens of different heights and lengths, heights 1-100mm and  length: 200-300mm. You input your height and length for how many pens you want. (maybe you want a pen of height 50mm and length 200mm and a pen of height 55mm and length of 300mm)

And after you put in sizes for different pens you submit it and you products appear.

I hope you understand, I'm sorry for my awful english :(

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAkA9.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you are currently trying and the problem you are having with said code. Currently your question is simply asking for a filtering system to be written for you.

Comment: this might be helpful :http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195056/i-want-to-filter-my-products-with-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which approach you are using to make such a shop. Considering that you want to start from scratch, here are few steps to create such a shop with WordPress:

1- Install a WooCommerce compatible theme. You can start with [any free theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/search/woocommerce/).

2- Install [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) plugin.

2- Setup your products and attributes. Check out the documentation [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/).

3- Use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/) plugin to setup your sidebar filters for products.